# Python - Flask application stack: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, flask, stack

**Background:**

I am trying to understand and modify a source code available here:https://github.com/hfaran/slack-export-viewer. This program will help to read to Slack archive message. By default, the program will display all the slack channels on the side bar.

**Requirement:**

I am trying to modify the source code to display only filtered channels. I have added few lines on the original code to achieve this:

```
channel = ['updates']
channel_list = reader.compile_channels(channels)
if channel in channel_list:
    a.append(channel)
top = flask._app_ctx_stack
top.channels = a
```

I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am trying to display channels, which are part of channel[]. Ho do I achieve this.

This code available online, I am sharing here for quick reference.

**slackviewer/main.py**

```
import webbrowser

import click
import flask

from slackviewer.app import app
from slackviewer.archive import extract_archive
from slackviewer.reader import Reader
from slackviewer.utils.click import envvar, flag_ennvar


def configure_app(app, archive, channels, no_sidebar, no_external_references, debug):
    app.debug = debug
    app.no_sidebar = no_sidebar
    app.no_external_references = no_external_references
    if app.debug:
        print("WARNING: DEBUG MODE IS ENABLED!")
    app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True

    path = extract_archive(archive)
    reader = Reader(path)
    channel = ['updates']
    channel_list = reader.compile_channels(channels)
    if channel in channel_list:
        a.append(channel)
    top = flask._app_ctx_stack
    top.channels = a
    top.groups = reader.compile_groups()
    top.dms = reader.compile_dm_messages()
    top.dm_users = reader.compile_dm_users()
    top.mpims = reader.compile_mpim_messages()
    top.mpim_users = reader.compile_mpim_users()


@click.command()
@click.option('-p', '--port', default=envvar('SEV_PORT', '5000'),
              type=click.INT, help="Host port to serve your content on")
@click.option("-z", "--archive", type=click.Path(), required=True,
              default=envvar('SEV_ARCHIVE', ''),
              help="Path to your Slack export archive (.zip file or directory)")
@click.option('-I', '--ip', default=envvar('SEV_IP', 'localhost'),
              type=click.STRING, help="Host IP to serve your content on")
@click.option('--no-browser', is_flag=True,
              default=flag_ennvar("SEV_NO_BROWSER"),
              help="If you do not want a browser to open "
                   "automatically, set this.")
@click.option('--channels', type=click.STRING,
              default=envvar("SEV_CHANNELS", None),
              help="A comma separated list of channels to parse.")
@click.option('--no-sidebar', is_flag=True,
              default=flag_ennvar("SEV_NO_SIDEBAR"),
              help="Removes the sidebar.")
@click.option('--no-external-references', is_flag=True,
              default=flag_ennvar("SEV_NO_EXTERNAL_REFERENCES"),
              help="Removes all references to external css/js/images.")
@click.option('--test', is_flag=True, default=flag_ennvar("SEV_TEST"),
              help="Runs in 'test' mode, i.e., this will do an archive extract, but will not start the server,"
                   " and immediately quit.")
@click.option('--debug', is_flag=True, default=flag_ennvar("FLASK_DEBUG"))
def main(port, archive, ip, no_browser, channels, no_sidebar, no_external_references, test, debug):
    if not archive:
        raise ValueError("Empty path provided for archive")

    configure_app(app, archive, channels, no_sidebar, no_external_references, debug)

    if not no_browser and not test:
        webbrowser.open("http://{}:{}".format(ip, port))

    if not test:
        app.run(
            host=ip,
            port=port
        )
```

**slackviewer/reader.py**

```
import json
import os
import glob
import io

from slackviewer.formatter import SlackFormatter
from slackviewer.message import Message
from slackviewer.user import User

class Reader(object):
    """
    Reader object will read all of the archives' data from the json files
    """

    def __init__(self, PATH):
        self._PATH = PATH
        # TODO: Make sure this works
        with io.open(os.path.join(self._PATH, "users.json"), encoding="utf8") as f:
            self.__USER_DATA = {u["id"]: User(u) for u in json.load(f)}

    ##################
    # Public Methods #
    ##################

    def compile_channels(self, channels=None):
        if isinstance(channels, str):
            channels = channels.split(',')

        channel_data = self._read_from_json("channels.json")
        channel_names = [c["name"] for c in channel_data.values() if not channels or c["name"] in channels]

        return self._create_messages(channel_names, channel_data)

    def compile_groups(self):

        group_data = self._read_from_json("groups.json")
        group_names = [c["name"] for c in group_data.values()]

        return self._create_messages(group_names, group_data)

    def compile_dm_messages(self):
        # Gets list of dm objects with dm ID and array of members ids
        dm_data = self._read_from_json("dms.json")
        dm_ids = [c["id"] for c in dm_data.values()]

        # True is passed here to let the create messages function know that
        # it is dm data being passed to it
        return self._create_messages(dm_ids, dm_data, True)

    def compile_dm_users(self):
        """
        Gets the info for the members within the dm

        Returns a list of all dms with the members that have ever existed

        :rtype: [object]
        {
            id: <id>
            users: [<user_id>]
        }

        """

        dm_data = self._read_from_json("dms.json")
        dms = dm_data.values()
        all_dms_users = []

        for dm in dms:
            # checks if messages actually exist
            if dm["id"] not in self._EMPTY_DMS:
                # added try catch for users from shared workspaces not in current workspace
                try:
                    dm_members = {"id": dm["id"], "users": [self.__USER_DATA[m] for m in dm["members"]]}
                    all_dms_users.append(dm_members)
                except KeyError:
                    dm_members = None   

        return all_dms_users


    def compile_mpim_messages(self):

        mpim_data = self._read_from_json("mpims.json")
        mpim_names = [c["name"] for c in mpim_data.values()]

        return self._create_messages(mpim_names, mpim_data)

    def compile_mpim_users(self):
        """
        Gets the info for the members within the multiple person instant message

        Returns a list of all dms with the members that have ever existed

        :rtype: [object]
        {
            name: <name>
            users: [<user_id>]
        }

        """

        mpim_data = self._read_from_json("mpims.json")
        mpims = [c for c in mpim_data.values()]
        all_mpim_users = []

        for mpim in mpims:
            mpim_members = {"name": mpim["name"], "users": [self.__USER_DATA[m] for m in mpim["members"]]}
            all_mpim_users.append(mpim_members)

        return all_mpim_users


    ###################
    # Private Methods #
    ###################

    def _create_messages(self, names, data, isDms=False):
        """
        Creates object of arrays of messages from each json file specified by the names or ids

        :param [str] names: names of each group of messages

        :param [object] data: array of objects detailing where to get the messages from in
        the directory structure

        :param bool isDms: boolean value used to tell if the data is dm data so the function can
        collect the empty dm directories and store them in memory only

        :return: object of arrays of messages

        :rtype: object
        """

        chats = {}
        empty_dms = []
        formatter = SlackFormatter(self.__USER_DATA, data)

        for name in names:

            # gets path to dm directory that holds the json archive
            dir_path = os.path.join(self._PATH, name)
            messages = []
            # array of all days archived
            day_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.json"))

            # this is where it's skipping the empty directories
            if not day_files:
                if isDms:
                    empty_dms.append(name)
                continue

            for day in sorted(day_files):
                with io.open(os.path.join(self._PATH, day), encoding="utf8") as f:
                    # loads all messages
                    day_messages = json.load(f)
                    messages.extend([Message(formatter, d) for d in day_messages])

            chats[name] = messages

        if isDms:
            self._EMPTY_DMS = empty_dms

        return chats

    def _read_from_json(self, file):
        """
        Reads the file specified from json and creates an object based on the id of each element

        :param str file: Path to file of json to read

        :return: object of data read from json file

        :rtype: object
        """

        try:
            with io.open(os.path.join(self._PATH, file), encoding="utf8") as f:
                return {u["id"]: u for u in json.load(f)}
        except IOError:
            return {}
```

I want to understand, usually, how this kind of scenarios handled and what are the other ways to achieve this requirement. Thanks in advance!

**Update: Adding full trace**

```
Archive already extracted. Viewing from D:\Slack\data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\slackclonemachine-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('slackclonemachine==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'slackclonemachine')()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\slackviewer\main.py", line 64, in main
    configure_app(app, archive, channels, no_sidebar, no_external_references, debug)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\slackviewer\main.py", line 24, in configure_app
    if channel in channel_list:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This error points that you are trying to take a mutable variable (i.e a variable that can be changed after its initiated), and pass it through a hash function.

Why is this problematic? If you change the value of the object, it the hash value will be changed as well

immutable object types:
bool, int, float, tuples, strings, integers

mutable objects:
list, dicts

Probably the `channel` object should not be a list

Comment: Thanks @gCoh, this is console application, I don't know to get the object type. How do I filter the data send to flask app stack. On reader module, is there any way, I can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback shows, your problem is in the `configure_app` function in main.py. You have defined `channel` as a list, which can't be used as a lookup inside a dictionary. It should just be a string:

```
channel = 'updates'
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, let me try with string and update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the condition

```
if channel in channel_list:
```

you are checking if a list is in a different list. In order to overcome the error, you need to change

```
channel = ['updates']
```

to

```
channel = 'updates'
```

(change list to string)

Comment: Similar to 'updates', I have multiple channels, how do I compare in that case. eg 'updates', 'sales', 'communication', etc.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is 'inner join', i.e the subset of two lists. this can be done by list(set(a) & set(b)). for instance the result of a = [1,2,3]  b = [2,3,4] list(set(a) & set(b)) would be [2, 3]

Comment: Yes, right. I want to display channels, only if it is part of channels list - inner join.

Comment: reader.compile_channels(channels) return channels to Flask for displaying, it fetches all channels for display. I want to add a filter at the display as only if it is part of channels list which I have mentioned explicitly.

Comment: ok cool so list(set(channel_list) & set(channel)) would do the trick

Comment: By using set operation, I got to know reader.compile_channels(channels) returns dictionary objects. I have to compare channel["name"] is in the set and compare with channel_list, I am testing that.